# Bond-wise, what happens at the surface of crystals?

Tags: atoms, physical-chemistry, crystals, atomic-physics

It's easy to understand the continuous phase of crystals (e.g. covalent like diamond or ionic like NaCl ). But how does the network ends up ? Network stitching by extra bonds (compare to the pattern) within the same molecumes ? H or other atoms/molecules plugged at the free bonds ? Or just starving bonds ? (which would soon turn into case 2 if not in vacuum, I guess).

Comment: This question is too broad, in my opinion. It depends very much on the material and the experimental conditions

Comment: I mentioned diamond an NaCl as 2 typical examples. Let assume ambient conditions.

Comment: There is a whole field of surface science to answer those questions. In short, it's complicated...

Comment: Probably depends a lot on the material and the surface energy. In the case of diamond, the surface is usually terminated by a monolayer of oxygen or hydrogen.

Comment: One of the keywords you want to be searching for (if you're not already) is [reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_reconstruction).

Comment: @Samuel: Diamond: thanks alot ! 
What about NaCl ? or maybe this ionic one does not (strongly) need anything special at endings ?
(BTW, Why not posting this as an answer ? )

Comment: @Chemomechanics: thanks, I didn't know this use of "surface reconstruction" expression. But is it only topology-wise, or does it include the case of different elements at endings ?

Comment: Reconstruction can involve both rearrangement and bonding of both intrinsic and [foreign](https://www.jstor.org/stable/71271) atoms.